# Omitting the last relation in the Wirtinger presentation of a link group

Tags: group-theory, algebraic-topology, knot-theory, knot-invariants

In my knot theory class homework I encountered the following question:

> Prove that for every link, when calculating the Wirtinger presentation of the fundamental group of its complement, you can always omit the last relation in the list.

I tried looking at the last crossing (in a given numbering of the crossings) and find another relation(s) that involves its three generators. It seems - although I can't find a way to prove it - that they always have to appear in other relations too, but I can't seem to find a method to express them. Can anyone help?

Comment: Can you remind us how the Wirtinger presentation for a knot looks, and which relation you use as the "last" one

Comment: Try proving that the product of all Wirtinger relators (up to appropriately chosen signs) equals $1$, so that the triviality of all but one Wirtinger relators implies the triviality of the last. To do this, geometrically, present the link in the plane with finitely many double points as is typical and consider one large circle enclosing the entire link.

Answer (score 1):

This statement is given often without a proof. For example in https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/knot+group#the_wirtinger_presentation we can read *Hint: If doing an example, do not throw away a crossing relation just because it is redundant.*. Moreover the same question has been already asked on Math Overflow: https://mathoverflow.net/questions/251292/why-is-any-one-wirtinger-relation-a-consequence-of-the-remainder (and probably more than just one time) but I couldn't find any answers so let's write one :)

Proof from Rolfsen's *Knots and links* (pages 56-60):

> The group $\pi_1(\mathbb R^3 \setminus K)$ is generated by the homotopy classes of the $x_i$ and has presentation $\pi_1(\mathbb R^3 \setminus K) = \langle x_1, \ldots, x_n | r_1 \ldots, r_n \rangle$. Moreover, any one of the $r_i$ may be omitted and the above remains true.
>
> Recall that $K$ lies in the plane $P = \{z = 0\}$ of $\mathbb R^3$, except where it dips down by a distance $\varepsilon$ at each crossing. In order to apply Van Kampen's theorem, we dissect $X := \mathbb R^3 \setminus K$ into $n+2$ pieces $A, B_1, \ldots, B_n$ and $C$. Let $A = \{z \ge - \varepsilon\} \setminus K$. The lower boundary of $A$ is the plane $P' = \{z = -\varepsilon\}$ with $n$ line segments $\beta_1, \ldots, \beta_n$ removed. Let $B_i$ be a solid rectangular box whose top fits on $P'$ and surrounds $\beta_i$. But we remove $\beta_i$ itself from $B_i$, and (in order that $B_i$ contains $*$) adjoin an arc running from the top, straight to $*$, missing $K$. The $B_i$ may be taken to be disjoint from one another. Finally, let $C = $ the closure of everything below $A \cup B_1 \cup \ldots \cup B_n$, plus an arc to $*$.
>
> (...)
>
> To see this, work in $S^3 = \mathbb R^3 \cup \{\infty\}$. Let $A' = A \cup \{\infty\}$ and $C' = B_n \cup C \cup \{\infty\}$. It is clear that $A' \cup B_1 \cup \ldots \cup B_{n-1} \cup C' = S^3 \setminus K$, $\pi_1(A') = \pi(A)$ and adjoining $B_1, \ldots, B_{n-1}$ has the same effect as before. But now we note that $C' \cap (A' \cup B_1 \cup \ldots \cup B_{n-1})$ is simply connected, being a 2-sphere minus an arc, and so is $C'$. Thus we reach the same conclusion without adjoining the relation $r_n$.

There is a picture on page 59 if you have problems imagining the above. In particular, $*$ is a base point above the knot diagram where all loops (elements of $\pi_1$) start and end.